# Marketing Cloud: ERROR: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, error-messages

I created this query and now that I put it in an automation, but I keep getting the error:

ERROR:  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key.

[image]
[image]

MY SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  J.JourneyID,
                 J.VersionID,
                 J.JourneyName,
                 J.VersionNumber,
                 J.LastPublishedDate,
                 J.ModifiedDate,
                 J.CreatedDate, 
                 J.JourneyStatus, 
                 JA.ActivityID,
                 JA.ActivityName,
                 JA.ActivityExternalKey,
                 JA.JourneyActivityObjectID,
                 JA.ActivityType
FROM _Journey J
INNER JOIN _JourneyActivity JA ON JA.VersionID = J.VersionID
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove your PK field constraint and run your query and review the data you have

Comment: What would this PK field restriction be? I already tried to create with the destination DE without a PK but it requires a PK
@EazyE

Comment: @ThaisCarolyne you can remove the primary key field and use the query type "Overwrite" and then try again

Comment: It worked out! Could you write your suggestion for my problem as an answer to my question? so I could mark as correct answer and close the question
@DucLe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a journey may have multiple journey versions and multiple journey activities, when you set the JourneyID field as a Primary Key field (force the value in this field to be unique), this may conflict with your SQL result.

My suggestion would be:

1. Remove the primary key field on the JourneyID field
2. Use the query type "Overwrite" and then try again